# Outputting windows' shell fc command to a text file including similar text

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, text-files

If I have 2 text files, call them f1 and f2 where

f1:

```
SometextA
SometextB 
SometextC
```

and f2:

```
SometextA
SometextD
SometextC
```

If I run `fc f1 f2` in command prompt, I will get an output like this:

```
**** f1
SometextB
**** f2
SometextD
****
```

I want to generate a new textfile containing both this output as well as the lines that are similar between them, so something that looks like this:

```
SometextA
**** f1
SometextB
**** f2
SometextD
****
SometextC
```

I'm honestly not so sure how to start with this, I know that I can write to a new file by doing

`fc f1 f2 >> f3.txt`

but I'm not sure how I could also add in the lines that are shared between the two.

This is for a project that the rest of it is being run in Python3, so if there's anything from that angle I can do to get the output, that would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: I believe that `fc` actually shows at least the line before and after a mismatch, or do you want **all** of the matching lines to be listed, highlighting the mismatches?

Comment: I'd look for an implementation of Unix `diff` written in Python and use that.